# Practical way to find out if SMS has been sent

Tags: android

I am interested in how I can figure out if SMS has been sent from the device.

In order to get notification when SMS is recieved, we use a broadcaster with:

```
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
```

Important to mention that I do not send SMS from my app, I just should listen when SMS is sent from the device.

May be I should listen to some Content provider (which somehow related with SMS) and react for that change. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to listen SMS ContentProvider by using **`ContentObserver`**

Here is my example for Outgoing SMS:

First register a ContetObserver with **content://sms/**

```
   public class Smssendservice extends Service{

       @Override  
       public void onCreate() {
            SmsContent content = new SmsContent(new Handler());  
            // REGISTER ContetObserver 
            this.getContentResolver().
                registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), true, SMSObserver);  
       } 

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return null;
       }
```

**SMSObserver.class**

```
       public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver {
            private Handler m_handler = null;

            public SMSObserver(SMSLogger handler){
                 super(handler);
                 m_handler = handler;
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(bSelfChange);
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");

            Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null,
                 null, null);
            cur.moveToNext();

            String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));

            if(protocol == null) {
         //the message is sent out just now     
            }               
            else {
                 //the message is received just now   
            }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Would this trigger if a SMS was removed as well?

Comment: @tidbeck :no,not trigger when  SMS was removed from ContentProvider

Comment: Inside SMSObserver.class there is is `Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().....`. To what related `getContentResolver()` ? Because eclipse show this one as error.

Comment: @Jviaches: please see my updated edit.i have implement full code in a service.

Comment: While this is working perfectly, may I ask if the user sends a multi-part message, will it be counted as 1 or is there any way to check this scenario?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  can u tell me i dont need to use service i just want when user come inside my app i will show simply count of sent messages to the user ? how will i do ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK How do you position the cursor on the last sent/reveived message? I see `cur.moveToNext()`, but can it be just any message?

Comment: @18446744073709551615, `getContentResolver().query` returns a cursor that points to the last entry in the URI

Comment: @midhunhk yeah, it is just on some phones that you need to specify the default order explicitly and null does not work.

Comment: @18446744073709551615, ok. I am not aware of that. Can yopu give some examples of such devices?

Comment: midhunhk IIRC something from LG. I cannot be more specific now, months have passed since then. But I could find the lines of code like: `cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, cursorProjection, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);` I remember that one `DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER` has fixed a bug, and was copied to other `query()` calls just in case.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thanks for help. But in my case, protocol is never `null` (it is "0" in either cases). Is there any preference for using `Telephony.Sms.PROTOCOL` over using `Telephony.Sms.TYPE` and checking if it is `MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX` or not?

Comment: On Android API 16 I've tested this piece of code, and the observer is not notified of a change on content://sms, then the code is not called at all. I checked the logcat console, and it write that the content://sms and content://sms/queued are really updated when I send a SMS.. any idea ?

Comment: what is SmsContent? shouldn't it be SMSObserver (the class defined right after) instead?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is using the logcat log. Every time a SMS is sent/received there is a specific entry. Just hook up your phone in debug and test and you will observe the specific entry.

I should mention this method is done from your app, so you can work it into your code.

Take a pull of [this](http://code.google.com/p/anroid-logcat-record-tools/source/checkout). There may be other methods but that seems fairly easy and do-able.