# How to delete same sms that was captured on onReceive method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please some one tell me that how I can delete the same message that I was captured on the onReceive method. Actualy, I wish that when a massage is received on onReceive method it was first use off and after use it delete but how i dont know so please help me in case.
Code that I am using also tag with this thread.

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,final Intent intents){
    if (intents.getAction().equals(ConstantClass.SMS_RECEIVED)) {
    new Thread(){
    Context context;
    Thread Set(Context ctx){
    this.context=ctx;
    return this;
    }
    public void run(){
    try{
    Bundle bundle = intents.getExtras();            
    if (bundle != null) {
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    String msg=null;
    String address = null;
    for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
    msg = message.getMessageBody();
    address = message.getOriginatingAddress();
    }
    dba.Open();
    int id = dba.getCordiId(address);
    int count = dba.getDeviceCount(ConstantClass.dbName[1]);
    if(count<=0){
    dba.InsertCurrentCoord(id,id);
    }else{
    Strsql = new String("UPDATE " + ConstantClass.dbName[1] + " SET " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_ReceiverCoord + " = " + 
    Integer.toString(id) + " WHERE " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_ID + " = ?");
    dba.UpdateQuery(Strsql, Integer.toString(id));
    }
    dba.Close();
    ////////////sending to SMSSync class//////////////
    MainThread th = new MainThread(sync,msg);
    try{
    th.thread.join();
    }catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(msg.substring(3, 4).equals("2"))
    ConstantClass.isAuditrequestSend = true;
    }
    /*******after receiving the sms opening the Main Screen.*****************/
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,ZigbeeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    abortBroadcast();
    /************Now deleting the SMS from the Inbox*********************/
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms"); 
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null);  
    int trId= c.getInt(0);
    int thread_id =c.getInt(1); 
    context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id),null,null); 
    }catch(Exception e){
    dlg = new ExceptionDialog(context,"On Sms Receiver",e.getMessage());
    dlg.show();
    }
    }
    }.Set(context).start();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Paste code with well-indentation. I have tried to format it but not indentation.

Comment: why you are first saving the sms then deleting you can directly restrict before saving in your onreciev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method and let me know what happens, just pass the context and number from where the message has came,

**Note:-**

> This is used to delete complete Thread for a particular number

```
private void removeMessage(Context context, String fromAddress) {

        Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                                       .query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            int ThreadId = cursor.getInt(1);
            Log.d("Thread Id", ThreadId+" id - "+cursor.getInt(0));
            Log.d("contact number", cursor.getString(2));
            Log.d("column name", cursor.getColumnName(2));

            context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.
                   parse("content://sms/conversations/"+ThreadId), "address=?", 
                                                     new String[]{fromAddress});
            Log.d("Message Thread Deleted", fromAddress);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Also, call this method after a delay of Thread like,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            removeMessage(mContext, "From_number");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be possible you are trying to delete a sms before reaching in inbox or before inserting in database table so register a  `ContetObserver`  for watching `content://sms` and when sms reach in inbox then delete it.see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520277/practical-way-to-find-out-if-sms-has-been-sent/9659025#9659025)