# Update current inbox message list

Tags: android

I am developing `SMS` blocking app in Android which block incoming message for blocked contact and store that message in my app database.Now I have created one `UI` in which I can read blocked message and also reply that contact(Just like chat view).Now my problem is that whenever I am in that `UI` and there is new message for blocked contact, I can't see in my `UI` , but when I close and again open that app I see that new message.

So my problem is how do I show new message in my `UI` when I am currently on that view

Thanks in advance

Comment: call ur adapter when sms receive

Comment: but when to call adapter ? I receive message in `BroadcastReceiver` and I show list in activity, so how would I come to know when to call adapter

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is listen for new SMS  by Registering [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html)   to content://sms/

See in that post how you can register a ContentObserver to content://sms/

[Practical way to find out if SMS has been sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520277/practical-way-to-find-out-if-sms-has-been-sent/9659025#9659025)

and you can also download working example from here [Contentovserver](https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Contentovserver.rar?attredirects=0&d=1)

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the most correct answer but what I did is I made static reference to my  `ListView` , `Adapter` and `ArrayList<MyObject>` and then in my `Activity` I added one static flag variable

`public static boolean isShowing;`

and `onCreate()` menthod I set `isShowing = true;` and `onStop()` method set `isShowing=false;`

now in my `BroadcastReceiver` I check if activity is showing than update the listview

in my case this worked for me, hope it may help someone else