# how to send sms automatically in android

Tags: android

i am using this code to send sms automatically but is not working ,i am able to send sms by using intent

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent sentPI;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";           
sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
sms.sendTextMessage("+91"+"**********", null, "hii param", sentPI, null);           
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms sent check your inbox",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: sManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);

Comment: r u using permissions in manifest files?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
use this aswell

Comment: i am using this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

Comment: @ParamatmaSharanUpadhyay Is there any error? Is you balance being deducted?

Comment: Thanks @ K neeraj i did minor mistake my code is working fine ,problem was in my device

Answer (score 1):

Use Permissions in your **Android.manifest** file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

And then invoke the SmsManager i.e

```
SmsManager managerForSms = SmsManager.getDefault();
managerForSms.sendTextMessage("Your text message");
```

Or you may refer to this Stack's question [How to send sms in Android. (See accepted Answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620150/can-i-automatically-send-sms-without-the-user-need-to-approve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg){
try {      
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);    
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
} 
}
```

And use this permission in your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

**Update:**

Add your country code before pass the phone number

```
 String phoneNo="+91"+editText.getText().toString();
```

**Update 2:**

Another possible cause for not working

If u are testing this code in dual sim phone then sim slot 1 always keep active otherwise it " no service" error.

reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32090923/3879847

Answer (score 0):

Code Which works for me is this.. Before you need to provide permission in manifest and also need to ask during runtime

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

and in Activity

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String number = SMSEditText.getText().toString();
            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, Message, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

also if message lenght is greater than  140 or something.. **you need to split the message** otherwise. it wont work .. which can be acheived by mulitpart text message