# how to listen for outgoing sms sending confirmation?

Tags: android, sms

Please it is possible to listen outgoing sms whether the SMS is sent or if he is not sent.a kind of acknowledgment of receipt.

Comment: If you are sending SMS programmatically from your app, then you can get acknowledgement for the same. kindly refer [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/sending-sms-in-background-from-an-android-application/) and [this](http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1693564/)

Comment: It's possible to track messages sent from your own app, if that's what you mean. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673595/how-to-get-sms-sent-confirmation-for-each-contact-person-in-android/24845193#24845193