# How read JPendingIntent in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, sms, sendmessage

how to read `deliveryIntent` in this code?

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.Telephony;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  smsTo: JString;
  smsManager: JSmsManager;
begin
  smsManager := TJSmsManager.JavaClass.getDefault;
  smsTo := StringToJString(ENum.text);
  PendIntent1:=TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getBroadcast();
  PendIntent2:=TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getBroadcast();
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsTo, nil, StringToJString(MSms.lines.text),PendIntent1,PendIntent2);
end;
```

Because I understand that SMS is gone or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [`SmsManager.sendTextMessage()` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), you are supposed to provide your own `Intent` objects (`JIntent` in Delphi) that are wrapped in `PendingIntent` objects (`JPendingIntent` in Delphi).

So, you would create two `Intent` objects that have the desired action strings assigned to them, and then wrap them inside of two `PendingIntent` objects using the [`PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) method (`TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getBroadcast()` in Delphi), and then pass those to `sendTextMessage()` in the `sentIntent` and `deliveryIntent` parameters, respectively.

After the SMS has been sent/failed, the `Intent` inside of the `sentIntent` parameter will be broadcast.  If the SMS is successfully delivered to the recipient, the `Intent` inside of the `deliveryIntent` parameter will be broadcast.

To process those `Intent` objects, you need to create and register a `broadcastReceiver` in your app.  When you receive a broadcasted `Intent`, then you can retrieve its `action` value (see the `Intent.getAction()` method) and act accordingly.

There are no `String` conversions involved, unless you want to convert between a Delphi `String` and an Android `JString`.

Comment: According to you, I changed the code. Is it corrected? How can I show broadcast?
Such a result cannot be seen sending SMS.

Comment: You have to create your pending intents with the intents you want to capture, and like Remy said you need to use a broadcast receiver http://www.fmxexpress.com/free-broadcast-receiver-component-for-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android/

Comment: @A.K: Read my answer again more carefully. You have to create 2 `Intent` objects first, **THEN** create 2 `PendingIntent` objects to wrap those `Intent` objects, **THEN** pass the `PendingIntent` objects to `sendTextMessage()` and use a `broadcastReceiver` to receive the `Intent` objects. You are not creating the `Intent` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it on Delphi 10.1 Berlin:

1. Based on example of Java code, I took [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578689/sending-text-messages-programmatically-in-android/8579311#8579311) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673595/how-to-get-sms-sent-confirmation-for-each-contact-person-in-android)
2. Here is full code of Delphi Broadcast receiver. With this code you can catch intent, and ResultCode (getResultCode). [Here](http://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=7269) is a simple example how to implement it.

unit

```
unit BroadcastReceiver;

interface

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.helpers,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils;

type
  TBroadcastReceiver = class;

  TListener = class(TJavaLocal, JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener)
  private
    fOwner: TBroadcastReceiver;
    fReceiver: JFMXBroadcastReceiver;
  public
    constructor Create(aOwner: TBroadcastReceiver);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;
  end;


  TOnReceive = procedure (aContext: JContext; aIntent: JIntent; aResultCode: integer) of object;

  TBroadcastReceiver = class
  private
    fListener : TListener;
    fRegistered: boolean;
    fOnReceive: TOnReceive;
  public
    constructor Create(aOnReceiveProc: TOnReceive);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AddActions(const Args: array of JString);
    procedure SendBroadcast(const aValue: string);
  end;
{$ENDIF}

implementation

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

{ TBroadcastReceiver }

constructor TBroadcastReceiver.Create(aOnReceiveProc: TOnReceive);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fListener := TListener.Create(Self);
  fOnReceive := aOnReceiveProc;
end;

destructor TBroadcastReceiver.Destroy;
begin
  fListener.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TBroadcastReceiver.AddActions(const Args: array of JString);
var
  vFilter: JIntentFilter;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if fRegistered then
    TAndroidHelper.context.getApplicationContext.UnregisterReceiver(fListener.fReceiver);

  vFilter := TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init;
  for i := 0 to High(Args) do
    vFilter.addAction(Args[i]);

  TAndroidHelper.context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(fListener.fReceiver, vFilter);
  fRegistered := true;
end;

procedure TBroadcastReceiver.SendBroadcast(const aValue: string);
var
  Inx: JIntent;
begin
  Inx := TJIntent.Create;
  Inx.setAction(StringToJString(aValue));
  TAndroidHelper.Context.sendBroadcast(Inx);
end;

constructor TListener.Create(aOwner: TBroadcastReceiver);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fOwner := aOwner;
  fReceiver := TJFMXBroadcastReceiver.JavaClass.init(Self);
end;

destructor TListener.Destroy;
begin
  TAndroidHelper.context.getApplicationContext.unregisterReceiver(fReceiver);
  inherited;
end;

// usually android call it from "UI thread" - it's not main Delphi thread
procedure TListener.onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  if Assigned(fOwner.fOnReceive) then
    fOwner.fOnReceive(Context, Intent, fReceiver.getResultCode);
end;

{$ENDIF}

end.
```

Then

```
  fBroadcast := TBroadcastReceiver.Create(OnReceiveBroadcast);
  fBroadcast.AddActions([StringToJString(SENT_ACTION)]);
```

SENT_ACTION - can be any string, e.g. 'SENT' or 123 - that is ID for filter.

Then I send it:

```
procedure TAndroidSMS.SendSMS(const aText, aPhone: string);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  PendingIntent: JPendingIntent;
  vSmsManager: JSmsManager;
begin
  Result := seNotUpdated;
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(StringToJString(SENT_ACTION));
 // Intent.putExtra( StringToJString(EXTRA_PHONE_PARAM), StringTojString(aPhone));

  PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getBroadcast(TAndroidHelper.Context, 0, Intent, 0);

  vSmsManager := TJSmsManager.JavaClass.getDefault;
  vSmsManager.sendTextMessage( StringToJString(aPhone), nil, StringToJString(aText), PendingIntent, nil);
end;
```

And receive with Broadcast Receiver:

```
{ usually android call it from "UI thread" - it's not main Delphi thread}
procedure TAndroidSMS.OnReceiveBroadcast(aContext: JContext; aIntent: JIntent; aResultCode: integer);
begin
 // vAction := JStringToString(aIntent.getAction);
 // vNum := JStringToString(aIntent.getStringExtra( StringToJString(EXTRA_PHONE_PARAM) ) );

   // now change value, another thread is cheking periodically for this flag
    {Intel, Arm, write to a single byte, or to a properly aligned 2- or 4-byte value will always be an atomic write.}
  if aResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_OK then
    Result := seSent
  else if aResultCode = TJSmsManager.JavaClass.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF then
    Result := seRadioOff
  else if aResultCode = TJSmsManager.JavaClass.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE then
    Result := seGenericFail
  else if aResultCode = TJSmsManager.JavaClass.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE then
    Result := seNoService
  else if aResultCode = TJSmsManager.JavaClass.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU then
    Result := seNullPDU
  else Result := seUnknown;
 end;
```