# Android - Sending Many multi-part Messages will miss some of them

Tags: android, sms, android-service

I'm new to android development. I want to send some SMS Message from my background service that it will fetch some data from the server and send it to some clients. So far it was working perfectly till they added some description to text messages. Since then, some of my messages are not sent.

Here is what I have done till now :

```
for (MessageData messageData : result) {
    String message = messageData.getBody();
    String recipient = messageData.getRecipient();

    int parts_size = smsManager.divideMessage(message).size();
    if (parts_size > 1) {
        ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
                smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(recipient, null, parts, null, null);
    } else {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(recipient, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

I don't know if android can handle sending messages in for-loop or if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: add a breakpoint in the `else` block and run in debugger mode. then see if it is reached and check that the size of the message (with description) is less than 160 (the maximum size of an sms message).

Comment: yes it reaches there if the message is less than 160 and I checked the DB the max number characters is 491

Comment: it reaches the `else` conditional? if that's the case, it means your `parts_size` is not greater than 1.

Comment: no it reaches the else condition just when text messages are less than 160

Comment: oh i see. if the max number of characters in DB is 491, then it means your `parts_size` should not be greater than 3 (160 * 3 is 480).

Comment: maybe u can try using `if (parts_size > 1 && parts_size < 4)`, so if the message is broken into 4 parts, the `else` conditional gets reached and u can handle showing the user a message that their text is too long.

Comment: so you mean if i have 4 part messages it should send via regular sending message?

Comment: but as this link said http://www.textanywhere.net/faq/is-there-a-maximum-sms-message-length it can send till 918 characters there should be no problem

Comment: i see. what is the DB storing? also, u never use `result` in ur for-each-loop. should you be using `result`.getBody() instead of `messageData`.getBody() ?

Comment: im using messageData result is a list of object that store body and number!

Comment: oh right, i had it backwards. what is ur DB storing?

Comment: it stores messages in a column nvarchar

Comment: Using an unthrottled loop to send SMS is not a great idea. You can usually get away with it for a small number of relatively short messages, but it can easily lead to a silent failure for multiple/long messages. You'll want to wait to send a message until the previous one has completed. Each `SmsManager#send*()` method takes `PendingIntent` arguments that you can use to fire an `Intent` when a send is complete. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24845193) has a simple example of how to do that for single-part messages. For multipart, it would be similar, but you would provide an...

Comment: ...`ArrayList` of `PendingIntent`s instead, one for each part. When the previous message's final part's `Intent` fires, then you would send the next message. Also, you can just use `sendMultipartTextMessage()` for everything. It will handle the single-part messages as well.

Comment: thank you Mike M. can you give me code sample ? by the way i was looking for that i will be thankful if you add your comments as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to follow and use [Mike M's very insightful guidance and code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24845193/3482621) to write an SMS message sending service that enqueues (large or small) messages and waits for each message to be completely sent before sending the next one. Most of the real work is done in the background.

[SmsService.java is a gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/albertcbraun/e7ec75c3a37a71b40cb395da522281ad) because it's a bit large to paste here.

One of my goals was to see if I could put the necessary functionality into one single android component. It's been tested with small numbers of messages but it's still experimental. (e.g. it avoids using a BroadcastReceiver, relies on the uniqueness of Service startIds sent in by the system, heavily relies on intents to represent messages, etc.)

The class has three static methods for setting it up, sending messages, and tearing it down:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SmsService.setup(this);
}

private void sendMyMessages() {
    SmsService.send(this, recipient, sender, "the message text");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {     
    SmsService.teardown(this);
    ...
}
```