# SmsManager : how to find the specific sms that was not sent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, smsmanager

I everybody, sorry for bad english, google is my friend... ;-)

I am developing an application which sends an SMS to a recipient when a button is pressed (several buttons, several recipients ...), when an SMS is not sent, I am able to catch the error (RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE , RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE, RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU, RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF, etc.). I would like to know the specific SMS that was not sent ...

Example : I want to tell "SMS to 111-222-3333 was not sent"...

Thanks a lot !

Patrick

This is how i send SMS:

```
public void sendSmsByManager(String noTelephone, String message ) {
    try {
        // Get the default instance of the SmsManager
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        //réponse pour sms envoyé

        PendingIntent piSent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
        //réponse pour sms reçu
        PendingIntent piDelivered=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

        //envoi
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(noTelephone,
                null,
                message,
                piSent,
                piDelivered);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message envoyé !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Erreur lors de l'envoi du message texte !  Vérifiez les permissions de l'application...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how i catch the error:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    smsSentReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        
@Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Le message texte a été envoyé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erreur: Pas de service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erreur: Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    smsDeliveredReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Le message texte a été envoyé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Le message texte n'a pas été envoyé", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
    registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));
```

}

Comment: You might have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24845193).

Comment: I will check the content of this answer in the coming days, but at first glance, it seems to meet my expectations. Thank you very much, I will give you an update soon.